# Woocommerce import csv shows a blank page

Tags: woocommerce

I am running on WooCommerce 3.1.1 and Wordpress 4.8.1. I try to import products (10 only) through built in import feature from "Products" -> "Import".

I choose .csv file in the first step and proceed further. Unfortunately, the second step (Column mapping) shows a blank page.

I have enabled WP debug mode and error logging. Still no luck. I don't see any warning or error in any of the log files.

What could be the issue ?

Here is the CSV File I use to import.

```
id,Type,SKU,Name,Published,Is featured?,Visibility in catalog,Short description,Description,Date sale price starts,Date sale price ends,Tax status,Tax class,In stock?,Stock,Backorders allowed?,Sold individually?,Weight (kg),Length (cm),Width (cm),Height (cm),Allow customer reviews?,Purchase note,Sale price,Regular price,Categories,Tags,Shipping class,Images,Download limit,Download expiry days,Parent,Grouped products,Upsells,Cross-sells,External URL,Button text,Attribute 1 name,Attribute 1 value(s),Attribute 1 visible,Attribute 1 global,Attribute 2 name,Attribute 2 value(s),Attribute 2 visible,Attribute 2 global
49,variable,1001-BB,HoHoHo Blackberry for girls,1,0,visible,,Blackberry coloured T-shirt for girls.,,,taxable,,1,3,0,0,0.08,11.2,,13.5,1,,175,300,"Tshirts, Girls",,,http://x/wp-content/uploads/1001-BB.jpg,,,,,,,,,Age,"1 to 2 Yrs, 2 to 3 Yrs, 4 to 5 Yrs, 6 to 7 Yrs, 8 to 9 Yrs",1,0,Color,Blackberry,1,0
52,variation,1001-BB-18M,"HoHoHo Blackberry for girls - 1 To 2 Yrs, Blackberry",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,3,0,0,,11.2,,13.5,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BB,,,,,,Age,1 to 2 Yrs,,0,Color,Blackberry,,0
54,variation,1001-BB-3Y,"HoHoHo Blackberry for girls - 2 To 3 Yrs, Blackberry",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,3,0,0,,11.6,,14,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BB,,,,,,Age,2 to 3 Yrs,,0,Color,Blackberry,,0
55,variation,1001-BB-5Y,"HoHoHo Blackberry for girls - 4 To 5 Yrs, Blackberry",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,4,0,0,,12,,15,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BB,,,,,,Age,4 to 5 Yrs,,0,Color,Blackberry,,0
57,variation,1001-BB-7Y,"HoHoHo Blackberry for girls - 6 To 7 Yrs, Blackberry",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,1,0,0,,13.3,,15.8,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BB,,,,,,Age,6 to 7 Yrs,,0,Color,Blackberry,,0
58,variation,1001-BB-9Y,"HoHoHo Blackberry for girls - 8 To 9 Yrs, Blackberry",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,2,0,0,,14.7,,18.3,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BB,,,,,,Age,8 to 9 Yrs,,0,Color,Blackberry,,0
59,variable,1001-BL,HoHoHo Blue for girls,1,0,visible,,Blue coloured T-shirt for girls.,,,taxable,,1,3,0,0,0.08,11.2,,13.5,1,,175,300,"Tshirts, Girls",,,http://x/wp-content/uploads/1001-BL.jpg,,,,,,,,,Age,"1 to 2 Yrs, 2 to 3 Yrs, 4 to 5 Yrs, 6 to 7 Yrs",0,0,Color,Blue,1,0
,variation,1001-BL-7Y,"HoHoHo Blue for girls - 6 To 7 Yrs, Blue",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,2,0,0,,13.3,,15.8,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BL,,,,,,Age,6 to 7 Yrs,,0,Color,Blue,,0
,variation,1001-BL-5Y,"HoHoHo Blue for girls - 4 To 5 Yrs, Blue",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,1,0,0,,12,,15,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BL,,,,,,Age,4 to 5 Yrs,,0,Color,Blue,,0
,variation,1001-BL-3Y,"HoHoHo Blue for girls - 2 To 3 Yrs, Blue",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,5,0,0,,11.6,,14,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BL,,,,,,Age,2 to 3 Yrs,,0,Color,Blue,,0
,variation,1001-BL-18M,"HoHoHo Blue for girls - 1 To 2 Yrs, Blue",1,0,visible,,,,,taxable,,1,4,0,0,,11.2,,13.5,0,,175,300,,,,,,,1001-BL,,,,,,Age,1 to 2 Yrs,,0,Color,Blue,,0
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Updated the question with CSV file sample I use to import. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had this problem and it had to do with invalid lines that WooCommerce can't handle. Make sure all the columns line up with the correct data. It could be it expects more numbers under id or your attribute 2 is assigned but doesn't have a visibility, but I'm not 100% sure.